# Test groups in spock?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, spock

Is there anything like TestNG groups in spock? I want to be able to run from console only fast unit tests or database tests or integration tests or everything. And whenever I run database tests i want to run some setup and teardown before/after this specific group. how can i achieve it using spock?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JUnit(4) suites for defining a set of tests to execute along with setup and teardown code. Filtering can also be done with JUnit categories and/or your build tool of choice. Depending on circumstances, it might be better to automate setup/teardown using the build tool.

Comment: but i need to execute the `beforeGroup` method once, while still having tests belonging to a single group in many different files

Comment: It should be possible to make this work with both approaches I mentioned. E.g. you could keep the setup method in a separate class and call it from multiple suites. Alternatively, you could implement your own test group feature as a Spock extension.